# Disable Adding Markers to Certain Areas of a Map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map that members can plot points of interest. I would like to be able to add "disabled" areas on the map that prohibits members from adding points to that area.

Example: If I add a point to the US Capitol, no members can add a point within a given radius of that point.

Is this possible?

Comment: How do users add the markers? How do you define/store the markers/disabled areas?

Comment: @Dr.Molle - a point is plotted and saved via a form. The Lat and Long are saved to be displayed on the map search. http://dev.ememorialmarkers.com/marker/add

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.  The way to go about it is keep an array of areas which are not allowed.

You can use polygons, or a point with a buffer, from which you will need to create a circle to check it.

You can do this using the Google geometry api.  There is a method to check if a point is within a polygon:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(point, polygon)
```

Then as the user clicks on the map to add  anew point of interest, in the click event before adding the marker, check to see if that marker location falls within any of the restricted areas, if so don't add the marker, else add the marker.